# Showing $\int_{0}^{1}{1-x^2\over x^2}\ln\left({(1+x^2)^2\over 1-x^2}\right)dx=2$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Showing

> $$I=\int_{0}^{1}{1-x^2\over x^2}\ln\left({(1+x^2)^2\over 1-x^2}\right)dx=2\tag1$$

$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}{1-x^2\over x^2}\ln\left({1+x^2\over 1-x^2}\right)+\int_{0}^{\infty}{1-x^2\over x^2}\ln(1+x^2)dx\tag2$$

Let $$J=\int_{0}^{\infty}{1-x^2\over x^2}\ln\left({1+x^2\over 1-x^2}\right)dx\tag3$$

Apply integration by part to (3)

$u=\ln\left({1+x^2\over 1-x^2}\right)\rightarrow du={4x\over (1-x^2)^2}dx$

$dv=1-x^{-2}\rightarrow v=x-x^{-1}$

$$J=\left.-{x+1\over x}\ln\left({1+x^2\over 1-x^2}\right)\right|_{0}^{1}+\int_{0}^{1}{4\over (1+x)(1-x)^2}dx\tag4$$

$$J=\left.-{x+1\over x}\ln\left({1+x^2\over 1-x^2}\right)\right|_{0}^{1}+\int_{0}^{1}\left({1\over 1+x}+{1\over 1-x}+{2\over (1-x)^2}\right)dx\tag5$$

$$J=\left.-{x+1\over x}\ln\left({1+x^2\over 1-x^2}\right)\right|_{0}^{1}+\left.\ln\left({1+x\over 1-x}\right)-{2\over 1-x}\right|_{0}^{1}\tag6$$

I am going to stop here. Evaluate these limits is not valid because of ${1\over 0}$. I have try substitution it looks more messier and complicated than this. I need some help, thank.

Comment: I can see close (1) show your self. Why are you voting me down?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have $$I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-x^{2}}{x^{2}}\log\left(\frac{\left(1+x^{2}\right)^{2}}{1-x^{2}}\right)dx$$ $$=2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-x^{2}}{x^{2}}\log\left(1+x^{2}\right)dx-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-x^{2}}{x^{2}}\log\left(1-x^{2}\right)dx
 $$ Let us analyze the first integral. We have $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-x^{2}}{x^{2}}\log\left(1+x^{2}\right)dx=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log\left(1+x^{2}\right)}{x^{2}}dx-\int_{0}^{1}\log\left(1+x^{2}\right)dx
 $$ and integrating by parts we get $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log\left(1+x^{2}\right)}{x^{2}}dx=-\log\left(2\right)+2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}=-\log\left(2\right)+\frac{\pi}{2}.
 $$ For the other integral we can integrate by parts again $$\int_{0}^{1}\log\left(1+x^{2}\right)dx=\log\left(2\right)-2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{2}}{x^{2}+1}dx
 $$ $$=\log\left(2\right)+\frac{\pi}{2}-2
  $$ hence $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-x^{2}}{x^{2}}\log\left(1+x^{2}\right)dx=2-2\log\left(2\right).
 $$ Fro the second integral we can do essentially the same argument $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-x^{2}}{x^{2}}\log\left(1-x^{2}\right)dx=2-4\log\left(2\right)
 $$ hence $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-x^{2}}{x^{2}}\log\left(\frac{\left(1+x^{2}\right)^{2}}{1-x^{2}}\right)=2.$$

Comment: I would to ask you @marco. How many types of integration methods are there? I know, substitution and by parts that is. Quite frustrating for me I can't seem to integrate most of them.

Comment: @Chinacat: In my humble opinion, you are trying to learn how to climb a mountain by learning first how to put a flag on its top. That can be effective, but quite frustrating. Anyway, you are learning from one of the best.

Comment: I totally agree with Jack. Except that he is one of the best here, not me.

Comment: +1. I'm sorry I catch a misprint: Just in the first line, it must be $\color{#f00}{x^{2}}$ instead of $\color{#f00}{x}$ in a denominator. Also, in the last line.

Comment: @FelixMarin Fixed, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The Taylor series approach is quite straightforward, too. We have:

$$ 2\log(1+x^2)-\log(1-x^2)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1-2(-1)^n}{n}x^{2n} \tag{1}$$
so by multiplying the RHS by $\frac{1}{x^2}-1$ we get:

$$ \frac{1-x^2}{x^2}\left(2\log(1+x^2)-\log(1-x^2)\right)=3+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{-1+(2+4n)(-1)^n}{n(n+1)}x^{2n} \tag{2}$$
and by integrating over $(0,1)$ the original integral turns into:
$$ 3-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n(n+1)(2n+1)}+2\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n(n+1)}=3-(3-4\log 2)+(2-4\log 2)\tag{3}$$
i.e. $\color{red}{\large 2}$, by partial fraction decomposition. We may also notice that:

> $$ -\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n(n+1)(2n+1)}+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2(-1)^n}{n(n+1)} \\= -1+\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{n(2n+1)}-\frac{1}{(n+1)(2n+1)}-\frac{1}{n(n+1)(2n+1)}\right)=-1+\sum_{n\geq 1}\color{red}{0}\tag{4}$$

and avoid partial fraction decomposition at all!

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\, #2 \,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
With $\ds{\quad\epsilon\quad}$ such that $\ds{\quad 0 < \epsilon < 1}$:
\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\int_{\epsilon}^{1}{1 - x^{2} \over x^{2}}\,
\ln\pars{\bracks{1 + x^{2}}^{2} \over 1-x^{2}}\,\dd x}
\\[3mm] = &\
2\int_{\epsilon}^{1}{1 - x^{2} \over x^{2}}\,\ln\pars{1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x -
\int_{\epsilon}^{1}{1 + x^{2} \over x^{2}}\,\ln\pars{1 - x^{2}}\,\dd x +
2\int_{\epsilon}^{1}\ln\pars{1 - x^{2}}\,\dd x
\\[8mm] = &\
-2\int_{\epsilon}^{1}\pars{-\,{1 \over x^{2}} + 1}\,\ln\pars{{1 \over x} + x}\,\dd x + 2\int_{\epsilon}^{1}{1 - x^{2} \over x^{2}}\,\ln\pars{x}\,\dd x
\\[3mm] + &\
\int_{\epsilon}^{1}\pars{-\,{1 \over x^{2}} - 1}\,\ln\pars{{1 \over x} - x}\,\dd x -
\int_{\epsilon}^{1}{1 + x^{2} \over x^{2}}\,\ln\pars{x}\,\dd x +
2\int_{\epsilon}^{1}\ln\pars{1 - x^{2}}\,\dd x
\\[8mm] = &\ \
\overbrace{-2\int_{\epsilon}^{1}\pars{-\,{1 \over x^{2}} + 1}\,\ln\pars{{1 \over x} + x}\,\dd x}^{\ds{\equiv T_{1}}}\ +\ \overbrace{
\int_{\epsilon}^{1}\pars{-\,{1 \over x^{2}} - 1}\,\ln\pars{{1 \over x} - x}\,\dd x}^{\ds{\equiv\ T_{2}}}
\\[3mm] + &\ \ \underbrace{%
2\int_{\epsilon}^{1}\ln\pars{1 - x^{2}}\,\dd x}_{\ds{\equiv\ T_{3}}}\ +\
\underbrace{\int_{\epsilon}^{1}{1 - 3x^{2} \over x^{2}}\,\ln\pars{x}\,\dd x}
_{\ds{\equiv\ T_{4}}}\ =\
T_{1} + T_{2} +T_{3} +T_{4}\tag{1}
\end{align}

---

1. $\ds{\large T_{1} =\, ?}$.
   \begin{align}
   T_{1} & = 
   -2\int_{1/\epsilon + \epsilon}^{2}\ln\pars{t}\,\dd t
   \\[3mm] & = \left.\bracks{-2t\ln\pars{t} + 2t}\vphantom{\LARGE A}
   \right\vert_{\ 1/\epsilon + \epsilon}^{\ 2}
   \\[3mm] & = \fbox{$\ds{-4\ln\pars{2} + 4 +
   2\pars{{1 \over \epsilon} + \epsilon}\ln\pars{{1 \over \epsilon} + \epsilon} -
   2\pars{{1 \over \epsilon} + \epsilon}}$} = T_{1}
   \end{align}
2. $\ds{\large T_{2}=\, ?}$
   \begin{align}
   \mbox{Similarly,}\ T_{2} & =
   \int_{1/\epsilon - \epsilon}^{0}\ln\pars{t}\,\dd t = \fbox{$\ds{%
   -\pars{{1 \over \epsilon} - \epsilon}\ln\pars{{1 \over \epsilon} - \epsilon}
   + {1 \over \epsilon} - \epsilon}$} = T_{2}
   \end{align}
3. $\ds{\large\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}T_{3} =\, ?}$
   \begin{align}
   \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}T_{3} & =
   -2\int_{x\ =\ 0}^{x\ =\ 1}\ln\pars{1 - x^{2}}\,\dd\pars{1 - x} =
   2\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - x}\,{-2x \over 1 - x^{2}}\,\dd x
   \\[3mm] & =
   -4\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - {1 \over 1 + x}}\,\dd x =
   \fbox{$\ds{-4 + 4\ln\pars{2}}$} = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}T_{3}
   \end{align}
4. $\ds{\large T_{4}\, ?}$
   \begin{align}
   T_{4} & = \int_{\epsilon}^{1}{1 - 3x^{2} \over x^{2}}\,\ln\pars{x}\,\dd x =
   3\epsilon\ln\pars{\epsilon} - 3\epsilon + \lim_{\mu \to -2}\partiald{}{\mu}
   \int_{\epsilon}^{1}x^{\mu}\,\dd x
   \\[3mm] & = \fbox{$\ds{%
   3 + 3\epsilon\ln\pars{\epsilon} - 3\epsilon + {1 - \epsilon + \ln\pars{\epsilon} \over \epsilon}}$} = T_{4}
   \end{align}

---

$$
\mbox{When}\ \epsilon \gtrsim 0\,,\ \mbox{we'll have}\
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{T_{1}} & \ds{\sim} &
\ds{-4\ln\pars{2} + 4 - {2\ln\pars{\epsilon} \over \epsilon}} 
\\[2mm]
\ds{T_{2}} & \ds{\sim} & \ds{{\ln\pars{\epsilon} \over \epsilon}} 
\\[2mm]
\ds{T_{3}} & \ds{\sim} & \ds{-4 + 4\ln\pars{2}} 
\\[2mm]
\ds{T_{4}} & \ds{\sim} & \ds{\color{#f00}{2} + {\ln\pars{\epsilon} \over \epsilon}} 
\end{array}\right.
$$

---

The final limit is a tedious one:
$$
\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{2} \over x^{2}}\,
\ln\pars{\bracks{1 + x^{2}}^{2} \over 1-x^{2}}\,\dd x} =
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\pars{T_{1} + T_{2} + T_{3} + T_{4}} =
\color{#f00}{2}
$$